# Casting properly int to string in SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server

Code:

```
string variablestr;

if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("table-of-int")))
{
    variablestr = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("table-of-int")).ToString().PadRight(32);
}
else
{
    variablestr = new string(' ', 32);
};
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type system invalid cast exception occurred
>   in system.data.dll.

I am clearly missing something.

Comment: What is the type of `table-of-int` column?

Comment: `reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("table-of-int")).ToString().PadRight(32);`

Comment: are those integer values definitely nullable?

Comment: some of them have null.

Comment: Integer *of what size*? When casting boxed value types, you need to use the exact correct type - you can't use `GetInt32` to get a `byte`, for example.

Comment: that column has int, lengt 4 and precision 10

Comment: you are right, someone changed the view this morning. i should have read a char. thank you and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your final result, I would recommend you do something like this:

```
string variablestr;

if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("table-of-int")))
{
   variablestr = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("table-of-int"))).PadRight(32);

}
else
{
    variablestr = new string(' ', 32);
};
```